# How to append text to a file in golang?

Tags: go

I find os.Open() return a O_RDONLY file and os.Create() return a O_RDWR but can't find a method return a APPEND file pointer.

Any help ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [OpenFile](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile) takes a flags argument that you can use:

```
 os.OpenFile("foo.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0660);
```

Used with O_CREATE , OpenFile can also serve the same purpose as os.Create()

Comment: Add `os.O_CREATE` if "foo.txt" does not exist.