# Golang "Access is denied" error on trying to write to file with io.WriteString

Tags: file, go, io

I am currently running Windows 8 64-bit and I am trying to create a logging file for use with a web server. The code in question is:

```
func LogWebPath(requestedURL string, accessedURL string, logFile string) error {

file, _ := os.Open(logFile)
_, err = io.WriteString(file, requestedURL + ":" + accessedURL)
if(err != nil) {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return err
}
file.Close()
return errors.New("nil")
}
```

Whenever io.WriteString is called, the error returned is `write log/visit.log: Access is denied.`

I have Go installed on my system and I am using `go run x.go` to run my Go source.

Comment: Do the `os.Open` method fail ? You don't check the error in you example...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are opening the file in read only mode. Instead of os.Open you might try os.OpenFile with the appropriate flags as shown at [How to append text to a file in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513375/how-to-append-text-to-a-file-in-golang) and [Append to a file in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151261/append-to-a-file-in-go)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I hadn't realized what sort of issue it was.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, you have a read-only file:

> `Open` opens the named file for reading...

You need to use [`os.OpenFile`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile) with the appropriate flags

#### Some examples

The common method for writing a file (used by `ioutil.WriteFile`):

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, perm)
```

To create or append to a file:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, perm)
```

To append only to an existing file:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, perm)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! That must be why I couldn't find the error, because I was always searching for os.Open.